# USB-to-UART bridge: protocol mapping?

Tags: usb, uart, microchip

I was wondering how does the protocol mapping work between the USB side and the UART side when dealing with the Microchip MCP2200?

What sort of USB transfer type is used?

- bulk?
- isochronous?
- interrupt?

Thanks for any clues!

**update**: I found a bit more info [Virtual COM port](http://www.lvr.com/usb_virtual_com_port.htm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like the [MCP2200](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en546923) is also supported as a CDC class device. In that mode bulk and isochronous transfers should also be supported.

Comment: Yes, it does support CDC.

Answer (score 0):

As it's an HID class device, it won't use bulk or isochronous transfers.

Comment: Your answer here does not make much sense considering the comment that you placed under mjh1007's answer. A CDC device is a separate class of USB device than a HID class device.